# Error when connecting in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, database-connection

This may be a stupid question, but I've been following a tutorial online for learning php and I'm using an exercise file from it that is a sql file. The instructor set up a username and password when the database was set up in the MySQL console in WAMP. I know it works this way, but now I'm trying to test it out in a different way by importing it into phpMyAdmin on my server, but I get an error when trying to connect.

It says the database connection failed because I don't have access to the "local MySQL server", and mentions a socket that it's trying to connect through (I'm not sure what that means). I'm wondering if it has something to do with the username and password I am using. Would that carry over in the file I uploaded from the lesson? I tried using the username and password the instructor used, and then I tried using the one I use for logging on to the phpMyAdmin page, but I got the same error both times. Is there another way to set a username and password or I am completely off and the problem lies somewhere else?

Here's the code I use to establish the connection:

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "xxxx");
define("DB_PASS", "xxxx");
define("DB_NAME", "tester");
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
?>
```

Thanks for your help!!

Edit: the exact error I get is

> "Database connection failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (46) (2002)"

Comment: Did you look at `mysqli_error()`'s output to get the actual error message from mysql? If it's saying it can't find the socket, then your PHP is misconfigured and can't find the mysql socket file. That has absolutely NOTHING to do with the mysql username/password you're using - it can't even REACH mysql to try logging in.

Comment: This is the only error that shows up:  "Database connection failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (46) (2002)"

Comment: then check where mysql is actually putting its socket, and configure PHP to look for it there.